# Bootstrap Carousel Stacking/Overlaying divs/items

Tags: html, css, carousel

I have tried looking through other answers, but to no avail.

I'm trying to make a simple carousel, with buttons to scroll through the items, not automatic.

The output, is that while the buttons appear, and css properties , font, bg color, etc, are implemented, the second carousel item overlays on the first - not stacked top and bottom but, taking up the same space, as seen below. The format and code was copied from the bootstrap documentation. I can't figure out why this is happening, any help is appreciated. Thank you!
[[image: overlayed carousel items1]

I have the following code,

(Also, these are the current scripts in the head)

```
 <!-- Google Fonts  -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,900&family=Ubuntu:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <!-- CSS StyleSheets -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ef786af6a6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <!-- bootstrap scripts -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```
  <!-- Testimonials -->

  <section id="testimonials">

  <div id="testimonial-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride= "false">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
          <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
          <em>Pebbles, New York</em>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
          <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
          <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>
        </div>

     </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#testimonial-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#testimonial-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        
      </a> 
    </div>
  

  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

! Yes I found the issue.

As you can see in my second carousel item class, the div class also set to 'active' like the first - this made both go on top of each other. Instead it should be only

```
<div class= "carousel-item">
```

NOT

```
<div class= "carousel-item active">
```

Once I removed the active from the second item, the carousel now works as it should, with no overlay.

This was found by going over the documentation again on the boostrap website.